# Is it proper to create a page just to generate a listing page (eg. for a custom post type)

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, pages

I find myself creating pages just as a "placeholder" to a listing page.

eg. I create a page "Blog" and "Portfolio". Both has the editor emtpy. And I just use it so that I can use `page-blog.php` and `page-portfolio.php` for the respective listing pages. It doesnt seem proper? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess another way would be including `'has_archive' => true,` into your register_post_type array and using archive-{posttype}.php to style your custom post type listings

Answer (score 1):

I only use 'placeholder' pages if I'm listing just a few custom post types with no pagination (or any other miscellaneous data for that fact), so that the end user still has control over the things like the title & content (which you can use for introductory text and so forth).

It also has the advantage of getting listed in `wp_list_pages()`, which is handy if you're using it for navigation elsewhere in your theme.

However, as @Daniel said, if you want to make benefit of a full-blown archive with pagination & feeds, opt for the `has_archive` arg.

I tend to use a different slug for the archive as opposed to the single post, just for clarity.

So for example;

> http://example.com/product/my-single-product/

And for archives;

> http://example.com/products/
>
> http://example.com/products/page/2
>
> http://example.com/products/feed/

The code for it?

```
register_post_type( array(
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'product', // defaults to post type name
        'with_front' => true, // prepends slug to single posts, default true
        'pages' => true, // support pagination, default true
        'feeds' => true // support feeds, default matches 'has_archive'
     ),

     'has_archive' => 'products' // if bool true, defaults to rewrite slug
) );
```

Comment: technically you can paginate a page containing posts, it's just a bit manual.

Comment: Of course, but at that stage you'd need a very specific reason *not* to use the `has_archive` arg.